# Two cowboys A and B decide to solve a dispute with a duel.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Two cowboys $A$ and $B$ decide to solve a dispute with a duel.
Cowboy $A$ hits his target $\frac13$ of the time.
Cowboy $B$ hits the target $\frac23$ of the time. 
It is decided that $A$ will take the first shot, cowboy $B$ will take the second shot (if still alive).
This will continue until there is only one left alive. Also, a cowboy can not shoot two times in a row. What are cowboy $A$ chances of winning the duel?

My logic is to simulate the cases where $A$ wins:

I Case:  $A$ wins: $\frac13$

II Case: $A$ loses, $B$ loses, $A$ wins: $\frac23\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac13$

...

But I don't know what to do from here. Any help?

Comment: You’re basically there.  Write a few more cases, and then see if you can come up with a general expression for case n.  Then sum that expression from n=1 to infinity.

Comment: Another way: let $A$ be the event cowboy A wins. A can win on the first round with probability $1/3$.  If A and B survive the first round, then the probability A continues on to win is just $P(A)$. So $P(A)=1/3 + (1/3)(2/3)P(A)$. Solve this for $P(A)$.

Comment: I think that should read: "II Case: A misses, B misses, A wins....". If missing always meant losing this math would be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track. A hint might be that A wins at turn k ($A_k$) iff all the previous shots fail (both A's and B's), and the last one does not (and they are all mutually exclusive events).
The chance of both of them failing is ($\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{9}$), and the chance of A hitting the target is 1/3.
Therefore the expression you look for is:
$$P(\text{A wins}) = P(\cup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}A_k) =  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{9})^k (1/3)$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $p$ be the probability that A wins. With probability ${1\over3}$ he wins on his first shot. With probability ${2\over3}$ he misses. When B hits in his first shot, A has lost. When B misses, A again has a chance of $p$.  It follows that
$$p={1\over3}+{2\over3}\cdot{1\over3}\cdot p\ .$$
This implies $p={3\over7}$.

Comment: This is how I'd do it, but seeing it beside the other answers I think of the anecdote: “Most people try to sum an infinite series.” John von Neumann, puzzled: “That's what I did.”

Answer (score 3):

What we have is a geometric series starting from $\frac13$ and the next term $\frac29$ of the previous. The sum is
$$\frac13\cdot\frac1{1-2/9}=\frac37$$